# Cleartool - find checked out files and who checked out

Tags: shell, cleartool

I'm new to clear case. I need to write a script to find out the files checked out in a view. It should be listing with fileName with directory and who checkout it.

I created **findCheckout.sh**

```
cd /vobs/vobElemnt
ct lsco -rec -cview
```

I executed

```
ct setview viewName
./findCheckout.sh
```

It displayed

```
21-Jul.13:39   idOfWhoCheckedOut  checkout version "./src/java/com/package/MyJavaClass.java" from /main/vob_view/view_integ/view_common_source/vobName_source_build/viewName/0 (reserved)
```

I only want to echo the `./src/java/com/package/MyJavaClass.java` and `idOfWhoCheckedOut`.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [`lsco` man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lscheckout.htm), you should combine your cleartool lsco command with [`fmt_ccase` directive](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm).

```
 ct lsco -rec -cview -fmt "\tElement: %-13.13En Version: %Vn User: %u\n"
```

That would display only what you want (you can remove the Version part  if you don't need it)

That way, the parsing to do is much simpler than trying to awk/cut/sed your way in the full original output of a `lsco`.
Build the output you want with the [fmt_ccase directives](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm).